# How calculate "pure" moving distance in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, distance

I write application which calculates total traveled distance. But I want get this value more less accurate.

My problem is when I not move, location manager always updates location and adds to my total distance ~ **1...2 meters every second** with **horizontal accuracy 10.0** . And if I stay / walk / stay, this distance will increasing on 60...100 meters each " standing" minute. This is bad for me.

I can stop updating location using Core Motion framework and detect changing x, y, z axis with CMMotionManager. This will work example when I walk. But when I will driving car the device will not change x, y, z axis.

How calculate "pure" moving distance?

Comment: You are going in the wrong direction my friend.I also tried this logic and failed miserably try using apple core motion framework its made for specifically this purpose.Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a property for pedomter

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CMPedometer *pedometer;
```

Initialize it like this
These function are currently supported in devices iphone 5s and above which contain motion sensor chips

```
 if ([CMPedometer isStepCountingAvailable]) {

            self.pedometer = [[CMPedometer alloc] init];
        }
        else {

            UIAlertView * alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Distance calculation is not available on this device!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
```

and finally get data in this handler

```
[self.pedometer startPedometerUpdatesFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                             withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {
                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                                   NSLog(@"data:%@, error:%@", pedometerData, error);
                                                   NSLog(@"distance:%@, pedometerData.distance);
                                                    NSLog(@"Steps:%@", pedometerData.numberOfSteps);

                                                });
                                             }];
```

Don't forget to import coremotion framework

Comment: Thx for answer. I hope CMPedometer class also supports driving in car activity (not only walking and running activity)

Comment: No for accuracy for that use this class https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivity_class/ this is specifically made for type of motion